# Database Derived Value same as foreign key?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, derived

Is database derived value the same as foreign key?

Based on connoly and begg books, fourth edition page 352 derived value is
`An attribute that represents a value that is derivable from the value of a related attribute or set of attributes, not necessarily in the same entity type.`

If we have 2 table such as, CUSTOMER and ORDER,

```
Customer
- Id_Cust
- Name
- Phone

ORDER
- Order_id<
- id_cust
```

Can we say "ORDER.id_cust is derived from Customer.id_cust" ?

Actually, I'm really confused about the concept above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, foreign keys and derived values are two different things.

```
product  quantity  price  subtotal
--
ACH123   5         $1.50  $7.50
```

In the simplified table above, "subtotal" is a derived value. It's derived from "quantity" and "price". (By multiplying them together.)

Database designers usually don't store derived values without using a CHECK() constraint or a trigger to make sure the derived value is always correct. In the table above, updating the quantity to 4 would make the derived value "subtotal" incorrect. A CHECK() constraint can prevent an update to "quantity" unless the update also has the correct value for "subtotal".  A trigger can automatically update "subtotal" when either "quantity" or "price" changes.

CHECK() constraints are usually a better choice.

Comment: so can we derived value from other table ? it goes like this 

There's table `A`
- A_Id
- Value1
- Value2

then there's table `B`
- B_Id
- A_Id
- TotalValue1+Value2

does `TotalValue1+Value2` counted as derived value ?

Comment: Yes, you can derive values from multiple tables. I don't think I've ever seen that done myself, though.

Comment: is that teoritically correct ? i've never seen like that either :( .

Comment: Yes. But I think such a design is likely to be a bad design for other reasons.